# Sharepoint 2013 - word documents do not show their Sharepoint title or name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, custom-list

I have recently noticed that my search does not return the SP document name or SP document Title. It is a master library and has both the name and the title fields that are included. It doesn't work for MS documents such as excel and PowerPoint or for ANY word documents (.docx).

When I open the word document I find this is the name that has replaced the document name and title. Is there a good reason for this?

Note: I have added word documents into a test site and it is not finding any of them. Perhaps the configuration is wrong. Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: What has replaced what?? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: My Document Library includes the mandatory Title field and it also has Name field. When the site is being searched it is picking up the title within the word document and disregarding the Title and Name fields within SP. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "the name that has replaced the document name and title"?

By default SharePoint search uses the Metadata Extractor Title to display the item title in search results.

Go to Central Admin >> Search service Application >> Search Schema

Searched for the "Title" Managed Property and moved the "MetadataExtractorTitle" towards the lowermost order and gave a full crawl

If the problem persists, you can try by creating a new managed property and map TermTile and Title crawled properties.

As per [this post](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013_05_01_archive.html) doing that with OOB Title managed property has no effect.

Comment: Thanks Itch. Ill give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: No success with moving the "MetadataExtractorTitle" downwards. Search is still the same. I am not sure how to create the new managed property.

Comment: This does not make sense - according to the documentation there is a hierarchy which runs from 0 through the number of properties for the managed property. In this case I have set the 0 value to the TermTitle which by definition is the title of the item in SharePoint. the second value "1" I have set to Title - so on and so forth. It makes no difference what it is set to. MS Word documents are "Titled" - which is their file name (under the document information). According to this documentation. I have moved to a testing site and added documents. No MS documents are showing

Comment: Why are none of my MS documents coming up in the search? Help!